# Play framework does not logging in start mode

Tags: logging, playframework, logback, playframework-2.3

I am deploy and start play framework using `activator start` . logs are logged in `application.log` file when I am using `run` mode. but in `start` mode , logging does not works while project is running properly and work fine.

start log:

```
[root@ops1 X]# activator start
[info] Loading project definition from /X
[info] Set current project to CustomerClub (in build file:/X)
[info] Wrote /X/scala-2.11/customerclub_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)

Play server process ID is 25682
[info] play - datasource [jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

I am using Java 8u20 on cent os

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some time using `${application.home}` parameter in logger.xml config file causes to crashing logging system.
You can [create a custom logger setting file](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger) and replace `${application.home}` with explicit address